# InfluxDB refuses connection from telegraf when changing from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, influxdb, telegraf

In my centos7 server, I have set up Telegraf and InfluxDB. InfluxDB successfully receives data from Telegraf and stores them in the database. But when I reconfigure both services to use https, I see the following error in Telegraf's logs

> Dec 29 15:13:11 localhost.localdomain telegraf[31779]: 2020-12-29T13:13:11Z E! [outputs.influxdb] When writing to [https://127.0.0.1:8086]: Post "https://127.0.0.1:8086/write?db=GRAFANA": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: connect: connection refused

> Dec 29 15:13:11 localhost.localdomain telegraf[31779]: 2020-12-29T13:13:11Z E! [agent] Error writing to outputs.influxdb: could not write any address

InfluxDB doesn't show any errors in it's logs.

Below is my **telegraf.conf** file:

```
[agent]
  hostname = "local"
  flush_interval = "15s"
  interval = "15s"


# Input Plugins
[[inputs.cpu]]
    percpu = true
    totalcpu = true
    collect_cpu_time = false
    report_active = false
[[inputs.disk]]
    ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs"]
[[inputs.io]]
[[inputs.mem]]
[[inputs.net]]
[[inputs.system]]
[[inputs.swap]]
[[inputs.netstat]]
[[inputs.processes]]
[[inputs.kernel]]

# Output Plugin InfluxDB
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  database = "GRAFANA"
  urls = [ "https://127.0.0.1:8086" ]
  insecure_skip_verify = true
  username = "telegrafuser"
  password = "metricsmetricsmetricsmetrics"
```

And this is the uncommented **[http]** section of the **influxdb.conf**

```
 # Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.
   enabled = false

 # Determines whether the Flux query endpoint is enabled.
   flux-enabled = true

 # The bind address used by the HTTP service.
   bind-address = ":8086"

 # Determines whether user authentication is enabled over HTTP/HTTPS.
   auth-enabled = false

 # Determines whether HTTPS is enabled.
   https-enabled = true

 # The SSL certificate to use when HTTPS is enabled.
   https-certificate = "/etc/ssl/server-cert.pem"

 # Use a separate private key location.
   https-private-key = "/etc/ssl/server-key.pem"
```